# Firebird POSITION unexpected behavior?

Tags: linq-to-entities, firebird

I have a table in Firebird 2.5.2:

```
create table SearchTest ( val varchar(20) )
```

which has two rows:

```
insert into SearchTest ( val ) values ('one')
insert into SearchTest ( val ) values ('three')
```

I want to select all rows where column 'val' contains either 'one' or 'hre'. Using linq I can express this as:

```
var a = from b in TestEntities.SEARCHTESTs
        from c in new []{ "one", "hre" }
        where b.VAL.Contains(c)
        select b;
```

This generates a query like this:

```
SELECT
"C"."VAL" AS "VAL"
FROM  "SEARCHTEST" AS "C"
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT
        _UTF8 X'4F4E45' AS "C1"
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X FROM RDB$DATABASE) AS "D"
UNION ALL
        SELECT
        _UTF8 X'485245' AS "C1"
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X FROM RDB$DATABASE) AS "E") AS "F"
WHERE ((POSITION("F"."C1", "C"."VAL")) > 0)
```

For ease of inspection though, this does the same thing:

```
SELECT
  val,
  substr,
  POSITION(Substr, Val) as pos
FROM
  SearchTest
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'one' AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'hre' AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
)
```

Using the search terms 'one' and 'hre', the result is as you would expect:

```
val   substr pos
---   ------ ---
one   one    1
three one    0
one   hre    0
three hre    2
```

However, if the lengths of search terms do not match:

```
SELECT
  val,
  substr,
  POSITION(Substr, Val) as pos
FROM
  SearchTest
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'one' AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'hree' AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
)
```

The match fails:

```
val   substr pos
---   ------ ---
one   one    1
three one    0
one   hree   0
three hree   0
```

If I cast the search terms (the cast types don't have to match, as shown here):

```
SELECT
  val,
  substr,
  POSITION(Substr, Val) as pos
FROM
  SearchTest
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT cast('one' as varchar(3)) AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cast('hree' as char(5)) AS substr FROM RDB$DATABASE
)
```

The match works again:

```
val   substr pos
---   ------ ---
one   one    1
three one    0
one   hree   0
three hree   2
```

Why is this, and is there a way around it?

**Edit:**

Jiri Cincura has noted that this bug is fixed for the next release; string constants are now converted to varchars explicitly. Firebird tracker issue: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-466

Comment: Why don't use SIMILAR TO operator?

Comment: What is the Firebird version? At first glance this looks like a bug, so you might also want to create a bug ticket on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird treats literals as `CHAR`, so when you have two literals of different lengths here (`'one'` and `'hree'`), it will describe them as `CHAR(4)`.

To illustrate this, the output in ISQL with `SQLDA_DISPLAY ON` is for a similar query is:

```
SQL> SET SQLDA_DISPLAY ON;
SQL> SELECT 'one' as X FROM RDB$DATABASE
CON> UNION ALL
CON> SELECT 'hree' as x FROM RDB$DATABASE;

INPUT  SQLDA version: 1 sqln: 10 sqld: 0

OUTPUT SQLDA version: 1 sqln: 20 sqld: 1
01: sqltype: 452 TEXT                    sqlscale: 0 sqlsubtype: 0 sqllen: 4
  :  name: (0)  alias: (1)X
  : table: (0)  owner: (0)

X
======
one
hree
```

Type 452 TEXT is the Firebird type for `CHAR` columns. The `sqllen` indicates it is of length 4. For `'one'` this will mean it is actually `'one '` (note the extra space). So when it is fed to `POSITION`, it doesn't match, as your original value is 'one' (as VARCHAR).

I am not sure if it is a bug in `POSITION` (the behavior of `CHAR` is an annoying feature of the SQL standard), or if the way Firebird uses `CHAR` for literals would need to be changed to `VARCHAR`. It sure is confusing though, so I would suggest to report it as a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE

Now if you were writing direct queries, the solution is as in your last example. Since you cast one of the literals to `VARCHAR`, the union will automatically convert all values to `VARCHAR`:

```
SQL> SELECT CAST('one' AS VARCHAR(3)) as X FROM RDB$DATABASE
CON> UNION ALL
CON> SELECT 'hree' as x FROM RDB$DATABASE;

INPUT  SQLDA version: 1 sqln: 10 sqld: 0

OUTPUT SQLDA version: 1 sqln: 20 sqld: 1
01: sqltype: 448 VARYING                 sqlscale: 0 sqlsubtype: 21 sqllen: 4
  :  name: (0)  alias: (1)X
  : table: (0)  owner: (0)

X
======
one
hree
```

Type 448 VARYING is the Firebird type for `VARCHAR`. Note that is length 4 and not the 3 as in the cast as Firebird will extends it to the maximum size found (in the second part of the `UNION`).

As you aren't writing the SQL directly, I am not sure what would be the solution here for you. You could add an improvement request for the Firebird .NET provider to cast the values to `VARCHAR` for these types of conversions (in the tracker at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET )

Comment: That explains it, thanks! I created a Firebird .NET Provider issue at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-466

My affected code is only dealing with about 50k rows, so I can work around this by moving the Contains() operation into memory for now.